# Json from a get API Call C#

Tags: c#, json

I have a GET API Call as below:

```
static void Main()
{
    RunAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("myurl");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("usr", "pwd");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);                   
        }
    }
}
```

How do I read the `JSON` response from the API ?

I was trying to do this:

```
 response.Content = new ObjectContent<Response>(new Response()
                    {
                        responseCode = Response.ResponseCodes.ItemNotFound
                    }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/json");
```

but I have not been successful yet. Could someone help please?

UPDATE:

My updated code looks like this now:

```
static async Task RunAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("myurl");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("BT", "pwd");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("");
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {                                   
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Product myprod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);

            var results = myprod.result;

            for(int i=1;i<=results.Count;i++)
            {
                var value1 = results[0][0];
                var value2 = results[0][1];
                var value3 = "Nilisha";
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    conn.ConnectionString = "Server=[xx.xx.xx.xx];Database=[Mydb];User ID=sa;Password=abc@321;Trusted_Connection=true";
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PortalData (LCID, TimeStamp, Name) VALUES ( @1, @2, @3)", conn);
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("1", value1));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("2", value2));
                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("3", value3));

                    Console.WriteLine("Commands executed! Total rows affected are " + insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery());
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }                           
            Console.ReadLine();                         
        }
    }
}
```

Are we allowed to use insert db calls inside the static async Task RunAsync() function ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Are you getting an error? what does `not been successful yet` mean? It does not really tell us what the problem is. clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach with the current example is

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

If trying to convert it to a strongly typed class then use

```
var model = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
```

UPDATE:

Based on sample data provided in comments the following was derived.

```
[TestClass]
public class JsonNetDateSerializationTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetResults() {
        //Arrange
        var json = "{\"result\": [[\"2016-10-31 01:29:42 495000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-01 22:29:07 169000\", 1033], [\"2016-10-31 01:31:51 550000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-01 22:41:11 357000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-01 22:41:11 357000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-01 22:52:09 848000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-03 01:48:13 038000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-03 01:48:13 038000\", 1033]], \"columns\": [\"ctime\", \"records\"], \"elapsed\": 0.000726}";

        //Act
        var actual = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(json);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);

        var results = actual.result;

        var value1a = results[0][0];
        var value1b = results[0][1];

    }

    public class Data {
        public IList<IList<object>> result { get; set; }
        public IList<string> columns { get; set; }
        public double elapsed { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Where the resulting values were

```
value1a => "2016-10-31 01:29:42 495000"
value1b => 1033
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried this: var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); Product myprod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json); String myvar = myprod.Results.ToString(); but it gives me an exception saying An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll on the RunAsSync() statement. Do you think it would have to do anything with the static keyword ?

Comment: Ok, I read that the way I've done it is the only way for console applications. What is the alternative then?

Comment: @Nilisha First I would suggest you inspect the aggregate exception and see what are the inner exception. It should identify what caused problem. could be bad data or something.

Comment: @Nilisha give an example of the model to be parsed and some sample data that is expected from request.

Comment: I found the inner exception, It says Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'columns', line 1, position 3331. So, I found it happens when json is invalid or the variable you are desiarializing is not json. I tried validating my data here: http://jsonlint.com/ It says valid. Also, I put a breakpoint to verify that the variable I give to deserialize has valid content. Yes, I can paste the json here but there is a character limit

Comment: "{\"result\": [[\"2016-10-31 01:29:42 495000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-01 22:29:07 169000\", 1033], [\"2016-10-31 01:31:51 550000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-01 22:41:11 357000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-01 22:41:11 357000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-01 22:52:09 848000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-03 01:48:13 038000\", 1033], [\"2016-11-03 01:48:13 038000\", 1033]], \"columns\": [\"ctime\", \"records\"], \"elapsed\": 0.000726}"
 This is my sample json. I am trying to get the value for the "results" key

Comment: @Nilisha, The sample data given validates. look at example in updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a great library called `JSON.Net`. It supports converting native C# object's to `JSON` and back.

You can add the library from NuGet under the name `Newtonsoft.Json`

for this example I created some sample data in JSON

```
{
  "User": "John Skeet",
  "Age": 50,
  "hobby": [
    "dancing",
    "sleeping",
    "writing C#"
  ]
}
```

If I wanted to use the library I would first import the library.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

After that I would

- make the request
- read the response as a string and store it.

If you know how the JSON object will be formatted then you can create a predefined C# Class with properties. Json.Net will map the (exact) name of the class properties to the same name in the JSON data.

so for our class

```
public class Person
{
    public string User { get; set; } //Maps to { "User" : "value" }
    public int Age { get; set; }    //Maps to { "Age" : value }
    public List<string> Hobby { get; set; } //Maps to { ["value1","value2","..."] }
}
```

this would suffice. you can then convert the retrieved Json data using the method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(StringWithJson)` this will return an `Person` object.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried this: var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Product myprod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json);
                    String myvar = myprod.Results.ToString(); but it gives me an exception saying An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll on the RunAsSync() statement. Do you think it would have to do anything with the static keyword ?

Comment: @nilisha an AggregateException is an exception that bundles multiple exceptions and is thrown by a task. use breakpoints to debug the `var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` line and read the exception. then I can help you with the real problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [flurl](https://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/), it is as simple as:

```
var result = await "https://api.mysite.com"
.AppendPathSegment("person")
.SetQueryParams(new { a = 1, b = 2 })
.WithOAuthBearerToken("my_oauth_token")
.PostJsonAsync(new { first_name = "Frank", last_name = "Underwood" })
.ReceiveJson<T>();
```